# Remove radiobutton list Items

Tags: ado.net

I have a radiobuttonlist populated from a DB with five options bullets.
On a certain condition I want to remove option bullets 2 to 5 but surprisingly I can't remove option 3 ??

I am using the the following code:

```
Dim DRPlace As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        rdDelPlace.DataSource = DRPlace
        rdDelPlace.DataBind()
        Dim ZipCode As Integer
        ZipCode = CInt(txbZip.Text)
        If txbZip.Text = 10240 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To 5
                If i > 1 Then
                    rdDelPlace.Items.RemoveAt(i)
                End If
            Next
```

On the above condition the radiobuttonlist should only show the 0 and 1 options, but option 3 keeps showing while option 2,4 and 5 are removed???

Any idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: You should loop from index 0 to 4 if there are only 5 items. Also your code will surely throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException before reaching that, since you are looping through 0 to 5 but at the time i =4 you have removed 2 items and the length will be 3, you can't remove item at index 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the item at position **i** of the array at the same time that you are decreasing your list length. That is a very bad idea. You should verify that your list contains at least 3 elements before deleting anything at position **>=** 2. Also, if you want to delete items from position 2 to 5, both inclusive, that means you are deleting 4 elements, starting from position 3, so loop 4 times deleting the element at position 2 (using 0-based)

```
    Dim DRPlace As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    rdDelPlace.DataSource = DRPlace
    rdDelPlace.DataBind()
    Dim ZipCode As Integer
    ZipCode = CInt(txbZip.Text)
    If txbZip.Text = 10240 Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To 4
            If i > 1 && rdDelPlace.Items.Length > 1 Then
                rdDelPlace.Items.RemoveAt(2)
            End If
        Next
```